# Probably firestore bug when read data

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

It's really hard to find this problem cause it happens sometimes, and very lucky that i catch this error with logcat opened.

So the problem: When i open my activity and request data i can't see loaded data and get logcat warning

> [Firestore]: Listen for Query(exercises where myField == someValue order by   **name**) failed: ay{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or 
>    insufficient permissions., cause=null}

First idea could be - wrong index, wrong rules etc. But it happens as i said "sometimes" most of the time it works.

I noticed that it happens when app reads data first time or when change internet connection state back to online.

So looks like a bug, isn't? Probably you have faced with this issue. Can you help me.

Here is the simple block of code with an issue:

```
CollectionReference collection = db.collection("myCollection");
collection.whereEqualTo("myField","someValue")
.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
         @Override
         public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshot,
               @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                 //magic 
        }
}
```

Rules:

```
 match /someitems/{someitem}{
            allow read: if request.auth.uid != null &&
          (resource.data.enable == true || isAdmin());
          allow write: if isAdmin()
        }
```

Indexes(updated see comment below ):

```
someitems:
  title: asc
  kit: asc
  language: asc
  enable:  asc
```

PS: I use latest firebase dependencies

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably add your security rules and your index definitions to your question. This will help the analysis.

Comment: Please add to your question what Renaud Tarnec asked you.

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec, Yes, looks like you were right. When i opened my indexes found two different indexes for the same collection automatically created by firestore. I merged them. But i'am still not sure that issue solved, cause it is something like Schrödinger's bug - you never know solved it or not....

Comment: @ValeraKvip Not sure it is Schrödinger's bug :-) Based on the error log you had a problem with your security rules or a problem of query that is not aligned with your rules ("security rules are not filters", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query)